# Correct form to Slice an Array In C#

Tags: c#, arrays

i wanted to ask how to Slice an array without using Array.Copy.
I'll give you an example of what i want to achieve so you can understand me.

Let's say i have this Array. called Original

[ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 ]

i want to get a copy array from an starting index given some length, lets say i want element one to element 6 i want the code to perform the task such as

```
int startIndex = 0;
int lenght= 5;
int[] CopyArray = ArrayFromRange(Original, startIndex, length);
```

then copyArray would be:

[ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 ]
i do not want to use Array.Copy because i will loop this to get subsequent slices

so i would do

```
int length = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < OriginalArray.Length; i++)
{
     int[] CopyArray = ArrayFromRange(OriginalArray, i, length);
     // perform some operations
}
```

This would give me an array of 4 elements every time the loop executes it and then I'd do some operations. But if I did `Array.Copy` it would throw an `OutOfBoundsException` when the i in the loop gets the value 13 it would try to copy the array[15] which does not exists. I want to avoid these kind of errors.

I'm developing on Winforms, .Net 4.0

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Check out ArraySlice<T> which gives you a pure view of the original array without copying anything: https://github.com/henon/SliceAndDice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best way to treat your approach would be with IEnumerable objects, specifically using LINQ.
IEnumerable is an interface meaning "you can call foreach on this object". It's implemented for arrays, and also for some other objects used to query collections - part of the point being, you don't especially need to know WHAT those objects are; just enumerate each item when you need them.

```
using System.Linq; // put this at the top of the .cs, not mid-code.

int startIndex = 0;
int lenght= 5;
IEnumerable<int> CopyArray = Original.Skip(startIndex).Take(lenght);
```

I wrote that in notepad, so it's possible there's some small thing I missed, but that should give you what you need. You can skip the .Skip(startIndex) part if it's always going to be 0. To access each int:

```
foreach (int value in CopyArray) {
   // TODO with value??
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you may want to throw an extra `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` at the end of that otherwise its execution will be deferred and run every time its iterated. This means if the values in the original array change, then the `CopyArray` will yield the changed values as well when iterated. EDIT: You may also want to mention that `Skip` and `Take` are lenient enough that they won't throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` errors.

Comment: Ah yes, absolutely. That's not optimal for all use cases, but it sounds like it would be for the question at hand. On the other hand, there are some interesting cases where it's useful to have a variable that automatically does the filtering/sorting/etc each time.

Comment: @Chris Sinclair thank you both, that was what i needed.
I don't know almost anything about Linq but after reading the documentation of Skip, Take and ToArray() i was able to code it and more important, understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Array.Copy()` but you just need to make sure that the index is within range:

```
T[] ArrayFromRange<T>(T[] originalArray, int startIndex, int length)
{
  int actualLength = Math.Min(length, originalArray.Length - startIndex);
  T[] copy = new T[actualLength];
  Array.Copy(originalArray, startIndex, copy, 0, actualLength);
  return copy;
}
```

In your example, the last two arrays in the loop would be `{14,15}` and `{15}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer a method that returns a shortened array, I can provide one of those, but I am assuming this is what you want:(And yes, this has been tested)

```
using System;
namespace ArraySlice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] array1 = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 };
            byte[] array2 = GetSlice<byte>(array1, 5, 10);
            for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array2[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static T[] GetSlice<T>(T[] array, int start, int length)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = ((start + i) < array.Length) ? array[start + i] : default(T);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```